# Visual Studio Code: JS formatting adds unwanted newline

Tags: formatting, newline

I've been trying to find an answer to this, but i can't find anything. Hoping someone here knows a quick fix.

When i format code with alt+shift+f it turns out like this:

```
    app
    .get('/', function (req, res) {
        res.send('Hello world');
    });
```

I would really like to make it look like this:

```
    app.get('/', function (req, res) {
        res.send('Hello world');
    });
```

Does anyone know how to do this?

Thanks